# How to view one specified process message queue if the process's pid is know?

Tags: erlang

In the Erlang shell, [`flush()`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/c.html#flush-0) can be used to get the shell process's message queue.

Is it possible to know the message queue length of another process by knowing its PID?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Just use

```
erlang:process_info(Pid, message_queue_len)
```

The result will be a tuple `{message_queue_len, *yourdesiredvalue*}`

If you want the entire message list, use

```
erlang:process_info(Pid, messages)
```

See [Erlang specs](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#process_info-2) for detailed information and the complete list of valid data atoms.

Comment: process_info is really very useful function.